# Using ST_AsText() without session object

Tags: python, geoalchemy

I am storing gps locations as feature in a restfull api. The locations are linked by foreign key to "place" objects in a flask/sqlalchemy/geoalchemy framework. I would like to print a user readable string representation of the points that I store using ST_AsText like so:

```
class GPSPoint(Base):

    __tablename__="gps_points"

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    geom = Column(Geometry('POINT'),  nullable = False)

    def __init__(self, geom):
        self.geom = geom

    def toJson(self):

        return OrderedDict([
            ("geom", self.geom.AsText())
            ])
```

However the AsText() method does not actually return a human readable string, but some sort of function object.

Comment: Sombody gave me a pretty complete answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074414/representing-coordinates-in-geoalchemy2)